# division making zeros after decimal point in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal, division

I am doing below code in c#

```
obj.value = decimal_value / 100;
```

Where `obj.value` is a `decimal` variable in the model

`decimal_value` is a variable holding a `decimal` value

C# code

```
if (member["LOADINGS"] != "")
{
    decimal loading_temp = Convert.ToDecimal(member["LOADINGS"]);
    prem.loadings = loading_temp / 100m;
}
```

When debugged `prem.loading` gets correct value `0.0952` but when it get saved in sql server it shows `0.09000`

loading variable in model

```
public decimal? loadings  {get;set;}
```

eg: result

`9.52/100` gives `0.0952` but when it stores in sql server in a column of datatype `decimal(18,5)` it gives the result `0.0900`

Any idea for this ?

**Edit**

saving in database

```
premium prem = new premium();
 if (member["LOADINGS"] != "")
    {
        decimal loading_temp = Convert.ToDecimal(member["LOADINGS"]);
        prem.loadings = loading_temp / 100m;
    }

db.premium.add(prem);
db.savechanges();
```

Comment: can you show us how you store this in sql server ? Any code maybe ?

Comment: @GuidoG edited the question

Comment: we need much more information. What type is prem.Loadings ? What is db ? what does db.premium.add do ? Remember we cannot see your code. What you should do is set a breakpoint on `prem.Loadings = loading_temp / 100=;` and keep stepping into until you either see the value changing or send it to your database and capture the exact command it sends

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
declare @v decimal(18,5)

select @v = 9.52/100

select @v
```

returns 0.09520

Comment: i want to do it in C#..i get .09520 in c# but while saving to sql server it becoming .09000

Comment: Perhaps if you included some code in your question?